# Clear keys within an object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a component, which is sending as a prop a method to change the forms input value (like any basic form). after having the onChange working, I decided to add a clear button to clear all input values at once, therefore I created a method to clear all inputs.

Example:

```
class ComponentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formInputs: {
        inputOne: "",
        inputTwo: "",
        inputThree: ""
      }
    };
  };

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { target: { name, value } } = event;
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { formInputs: { ...previousState.formInputs, [name]: value } };
    });
  };

  clearInputs = () => {
    /* this is problematic, because I'm setting the input from defined to undefined */
    this.setState({ formInputs: {} });
  };

  render() {
    const { formInputs } = this.state;
    return (
      <Form 
        handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange}
        clearInputs={this.clearInputs}
        formInputs={formInputs}
      />
    );
  };
};
```

clearing like the method above is gonna give an error, because I'm removing the keys within state, which the form inputs have their values aimed to. no problem so I thought, I would just add all inputs within setState to equal an empty string like this: `this.setState({ formInputs: { inputOne: "", inputTwo: "", inputThree: ""} });` which works. but I have a lot of inputs which have to be cleared, so probably that method is not the most efficient either. that being said, is there a more efficient way to clear each within the "formInputs" object in state?

Comment: Extract the inputs object to a variable outside your component, on clear use the variable to update the state and also for initializing the state

Comment: definitely more efficient to state it once, and use that variable initially and for updating, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the initial state in a separate variable outside the component(or inside if you like) and use it not only to initialize the state but also to reset the state to it inside the `clearInputs` function.

Comment: yes, works better to set the variables once. thank you.